# How to get asset folder path in android native activity?

Tags: android, ndk

I am trying to create a small game with android native activity. I wish to load textures using stb image. I don't know how to get the path to assets folder. 
Is there any API to get path to apk directory so that I can use that to get textures? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Reading assets in C or C++ is actually very tricky in Android.

You need to go via the AssetManager, and in Java-side code, you need to do this in your NativeActivity class:

```
AssetManager mgr = this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getAssets();
```

And then pass this manager to your C code.

Actually reading assets can be tricky, as it is read from compressed archived, but there is an amazing trick available that remaps the FILE functionality.

Look at [android_fopen.h + android_fopen.c](http://www.50ply.com/blog/2013/01/19/loading-compressed-android-assets-with-file-pointer/) on how to do that.

With this trick, you can then `fopen()` and `fread()` your assets, and have the assetmanager do all the work under water.

Comment: Hey, Thanks. The fopen redirection trick worked.

Comment: @Ankitsinghkushwah i am glad it worked. Do not forget to accept the answer.